# How can a memory leak persist even after the program that caused it has closed?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I have a C# console program that is clearly causing a memory leak.  But aside from the issue of tracking down the memory leak, the really confusing thing is that even after the program shuts down and no longer shows in the Task Manager, the memory leak does not get cleaned up.

How can this be?  Maybe this gives a clue as to the nature of the leak?

Evidence: Here's Task manager, showing over 24GB in use:
[image]

Meanwhile, my process does not appear in the Processes tab, and a quick eyeball of the amount of memory in use by other processes, combined with the size of the scrollbar shows that there is **no way** that those numbers will add up to 24 GB:
[image]

Comment: Where do you see the memory leak?  Once the process is gone, all of its memory is reclaimed.  So can  you define what you mean by memory leak when the process is gone?

Comment: @LB2 well thats not true for 100%, in specialized environments such as Real-Time Operating Systems the memory may not be freed after you close your application

Comment: @LB2: evidence added to question

Comment: @Shaul That `Me...` field - which memory is it specifically?

Comment: @Shaul, the only time I've seen memory in use but not in the process list is then I've been on a VM with dynamic memory. Is that a VM?

Comment: @LB2: "Memory (Private Working Set)"

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars - yes it is a VM.  How does that help us?

Comment: @Shaul well Memory (Private Working Set) only shows memory that can't be shared by other processes, can you run there something like this? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: @Shaul. It's a guess. I expect the memory isn't being used by your C# program at all and that the used memory is an artifact of running a VM on host with dynamic memory configured. Run RAM Map (as advised by David), I think you'll find that the culprit is shown in there.

Comment: @DavidKaya - Thanks!  I ran RamMap and it's showing a process called "AWE" that is hogging 16GB.  What is that?

Comment: @Shaul That helps applications manipulate with large amounts of memory. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system uses AWE [Address Windowing Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows your SQL Server to quickly manipulate physical memory. Database management systems need access to large caches of data, but since the restriction for application is 2GB then those DMS get memory from AWE.

To "fix" this you have to set `max server memory` to smaller value, so your SQL Server won't use all of your memory.

Comment: +1. Very interesting, looks like on a 64bit system SQL Server uses AWE when the "Locked Pages in Memory" privilege is given to the SQL Server Service Account. 

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-530-awe-must-be-enabled-on-64-bit-servers/

Answer (score 3):

Could it be an artifact of running on a VM?

See this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saponsqlserver/archive/2013/08/31/virtualization-overcommitting-memory-and-how-to-detect-it-within-the-vm.aspx

Here's another more succinct explanation of what can happen on a VM with dynamic memory:

http://blog.luxem.org/2013/05/driver-locked-memory-on-hyper-v-guests.html

I had this issue myself, and was very confused until I found these blog posts.

Comment: Thanks!  These blogs address what happens when you have "Driver Locked" hogging your memory.  In my case, it's AWE hogging the memory.  How do I release that?

Comment: @Shaul You have to set `max server memory` in your SQL Server management, as that is what I think is getting that memory.

Comment: @DavidKaya, but then wouldn't the SQL Server process be the one using that memory, not AWE?

Comment: Actually @DavidKaya I tested your theory and restarted SQL Server.  Magic!  All the memory suddenly got freed!

Comment: @Shaul well, AWE is giving that memory to SQL Server process, because there is a limit of 2GB cache memory that can be used by application I think, so AWE provides memory for SQL Server, but when that maximum value is set too high, this will happen

Comment: @Shaul You still have to set that maximum value if you dont want this to happen again.

Comment: @DavidKaya Sounds right.  You want to put that as an answer?

Comment: @Shaul sure why not :) I'll write it all to that answer so other people with same problem will be able to fix it